# How to equally space an element between two elements from a header in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, format

I have a header that includes a logo and a logout link. The header is in an external page which I include using the  tag. I then have a title in the HTML file under the   tag. I want to centre the title automatically so that it is even space between the end of the logo() element and the logout() element. Such that:

LOGO< *equal spacing* >TITLE<*equal spacing*>LOGOUT

Here is what my code looks like right now:

Styles.css:

```
* {
    background-color: black;    
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
}
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right:10px;
}
h1{
   text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    align-content: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

header.php

```
<a href="home.php"><img class = "logo" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5d5a565bed5af400017a2c97/1614516482816-LL1JVIR67NFFN016FNID/THRIVE-LOGO-2_RGB_NEW_WHITE.png?format=1500w" width="300" height="50"alt="Company logo"></a>
  
<div class="header">
    <a href="logout.php?logout">Logout</a>
    
    <p></p>
</div>
```

set_goal.php

```
html>
        <head>
        <include src="header.php"></include>
        <h1>Please set your goal and choose your programme type</h1>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more than a way to divide 3 or any column. You can see **example** from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp). Also, you can use display flex.

Documentation Example:

```
<div class="parent_element">
    <div class="logo">child element 1</div>
    <div class="titile">child element 2</div>
    <div class="logout">child element 3</div>
</div>

<style>
    .parent_element{
        display: flex;
        align-content: center;
    }
</style>
```

**You have made another simple mistake in your set_goal.php file. You have added your header file and h1 tag, which means you have added elements under the head element, this is not valid.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` and `align-content: center;` in the header element style. it will center all automatically.

You can also use `gap: 1rem;` in the header element as well to give the same space between the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use justify-content and align-items together with the display: flex; for get better positioned elements.

You can check this page for more info about display and the property align-items and justify-content:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp#align-content